# Is there a way in SQL server we can attach a tempdb of a different server

Tags: sql-server

I was wondering if there is a way in SQL server to attach a tempdb of a different server, giving it a different name while attaching maybe.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish by doing this?  Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

tempdb is recreated every time your server restarted. Files of this database does not guaranteed to be consistent (ldf writes can be cached). Backups are impossible.

So you can not do any reasonable and usable attachment a tempdb.